# Browsing to a site on port 8080 Windows Server 2008 IIS 7

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

I have a Win 2008 Server VPS with IIS 7

I created a new site (alongside with the Default site that runs on port 80). The new site was given a port 8080.

From my local dev machine, if i browse to the site using:

http://66.71.xxx.xxx:8080/

I get a not found error. If I go to:

http://66.71.xxx.xxx

then I see the IIS 7.0 page.

From the server, I can browse the site with port 8080, why can't I do it from outside the network?

Also, can I have a Default site running on a location other than c:\inetpub\wwwroot without jumping through a bunch of hoops?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is the server sitting behind a firewall that only opens port 80, not 8080? That would be my first guess, but hard to know without knowing how the server is configured, where it sits etc.

Comment: How would I check if it's opening up only port 80

Comment: Ask your network admin (or whoever runs the firewall) to see if the port is open.  Alternatively you can (from your dev machine) do a "telnet server 8080", which will attempt to have a telnet session connect to the server on port 8080.  If you can't get through that way, then chances are something is blocking it, most likely the firewall.  You can also use wireshark or similar traffic sniffer to see where the packets are getting whacked.

Comment: Thank you. I opened up "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security". Now, I am not sure what I am looking for. I browsed through Firewall under Monitoring options, but not sure what to do.

Also, is there a way to set the Default Site point to a location other than c:\inetpub\wwwroot without messing up too many things?

Comment: @user25164 if your question is still not answered.. then you prolly shouldn't have awarded it the correct answer

Answer (score 8):

Here are the steps to create a Rule..

- Click Start -> Administrative Tools -> Windows Firewall with Advanced Security
- Click on Inbound Rules
- In Actions panel -> click New Rule...
- In New Inbound Rule Wizard..
- In Rule Type -> select "Port" -> Next
- In Protocol and Ports -> select "TCP" -> select Specific local ports: "8080" -> Next
- In Action -> select "Allow the connection"
- In Profile -> select "Domain", "Private" and "Public"
- In Name -> Give a suitable name to identify your rule e.g.: "World Wide Web Services (HTTP 8080 Traffic-In)"

For your second question check this out [Configure Web site content location in IIS 7 / 7.5](http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Did-you-know-Configure-Web-site-content-location-in-IIS-7-75.aspx)