# Unable to access port 8080 externally (Windows server 2012 r2)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, port, windows-10, windows-firewall, iis-8.5

I have developed a web-service on Visual Studio 2015 and using `MySQL` DB on `Windows 10`. I want to deploy it on `IIS`. So I installed it on my `Windows Server 2012 R2` by using [How to Install IIS on Windows server 2012 R2](http://thesolving.com/server-room/how-to-install-and-configure-iis-on-windows-server-2012-r2/). After installation I have placed a test `html` file and placed it in a folder through which I have given access to created local site. The port set to the site is `8080`. When I run it on my server it's working and displaying me the page. But when I want to access it on my system it doesn't shows me anything.

[image]

At server firewall is totally closed.

[image]

Also I have tried [this](https://serverfault.com/a/108565) solution. But still no progress.

**Note:-**

1. On server side, 80 and 443 is used by Xampp server.
2. At my system, 8080 and 443 is used by Xampp server. But I have also stopped it and tried to run the URL but still no progress.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: In the capture the IP seems to be `116.x.x.x`, it's that a public Internet IP?, I mean the server is directly accessible from Internet? Or it's some type of VM from a cloud services provider? (in either case completely disabling the firewall is not a good idea)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the binding in IIS is set wrong. Your server needs to be bound to either the public IP or the wildcard (*) IP address.

[image: this picture]

Additionally, if you are trying to access the server from an external IP address, it needs to have the ports opened on the firewall (or router if you are running it at home) which is presumably in front of the server.

Comment: It's not the answer to my question, server is already bound to public IP.